# Groups elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ be a group and $H= \langle(1 2 3)\rangle \times \langle2\rangle$ and $K=\langle(1)\rangle \times \langle2\rangle$  be subgroups.

1. Show in two different ways that H normal to G, k is normal to H and K normal to G
2. Find the elements  of H/K and G/H
3. Find an isomorphic group to G/H, and prove it with the isomorphism theorem

Comment: thanks for your help....... if im asking is because i dooooon't understand it !!!!!! and i really need it for tomorrow!!!

Comment: Of course, but you are expected to at least show what it is you don't understand, where are you stuck, what you've tried to solve the problem, &c.

Comment: first I dont understand my group G I Know that S3= (1)(12)(13)(23)(123)(321) order 6 and Z4=0123 but  s3 xZ4 ??

Comment: In your previous [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593498/group-order-and-left-cosets) you were explained a list of things. Did you read that carefully?

Comment: I did!... this is for take home test for tomorros and i have my final exam  friday!! im trying to understand it!!

Comment: $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z_4}$ is the set of ordered pairs of the form $(\sigma, n)$, where $\sigma \in S_3$ is a permutation and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ is an integer (modulo $4$).

Comment: G HAS ORDER 24??

Comment: G= ((1),0),((1),1),((1),2).....((123),0),((123),1)..??

Comment: Yes, $G$ has order $24$, but that's not particularly relevant to your three homework questions. See my answer for a more complete response to your homework questions.

Comment: no that another question of my homework thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To see that $H \triangleleft G$, let $(\sigma, n) \in G$. Show that $(\sigma, n) H = H (\sigma, n)$. By property of direct products, it suffices to show separately that both $\sigma \langle (123) \rangle = \langle (123) \rangle \sigma$ and $n+2 = 2+n$. A similar process nets you normality of the other two.
2. Elements of $H/K$ are of the form $((1), 0 \bmod 2)$ and elements of $G/H$ are of the form $(\tau \bmod (123), n \bmod 2)$.
3. Hint: in my definition of $G/H$, $\tau$ is a transposition.

Comment: $(\tau \circ \langle(123) \rangle, n \bmod 2)$.

Comment: Hmm, since $\langle (123) \rangle$ is cyclic, that notation really should be $(\tau \bmod (123), n \bmod 2)$. I've edited my response.

Comment: there is another way to contact you??? I REALLY NEED HELPPP

Comment: I would prefer to keep contact here on StackExchange so that other users can chime in while I'm away.

What exactly is it that you're still stuck on?